# Is there a specific word to describe a business legend?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to know if there's a word that describes a deceased business/entrepreneurial legend that revolutionized their industry.

Examples of the types of people I'm talking about include Henry Ford, Thomas Edison, and Steve Jobs.

`Industrialist` seems close, but means

> A person involved in the ownership or management of an industrial
>   enterprise

and thus doesn't convey the right sense of importance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Magnate:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/magnate) *a person of great influence, importance, or standing in a particular enterprise, field of business, etc.* I don't think there's any special word for *deceased* magnates (though they often are).

There's also [tycoon](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=tycoon&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=GoONTt22EKeb1AWr1IAa&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5b1c5ecdadada30&biw=1427&bih=920), but for me at least this suggests someone who is outstandingly successful at making money out of an industry, rather than revolutionalising how that industry functions.

[Mogul](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbs=dfn:1&source=hp&q=mogul&pbx=1&oq=mogul&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=31657l32813l3l33422l5l5l0l0l0l0l172l672l1.4l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=379f0797a08beddc&biw=1427&bih=920) is much associated with the movie industry of the mid-20th century. Again I feel this suggests someone who wields great power and wealth obtained primarily by business acumen, rather than creativity within the business. I don't normally think of of great movie directors as *moguls*, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You could call that person an *innovator*. To [innovate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovator) is to:

> to make changes : do something in a new way

For example, this [magazine](http://www.successmagazine.com/steve-jobs-master-of-innovation/PARAMS/article/1054/channel/22) referred to Jobs as a "master of innovation."

Answer (score 2):

*Visionary* is a perfect fit.

It's actually one of the words Apple is using to describe [Steve Jobs](http://www.apple.com/stevejobs/)

Comment: I just found out that this is the word President Obama used, too.

Comment: One can be a visionary without making any notable impact in one's own lifetime, however (da Vinci springs to mind), so I'm not sure this is quite the right fit for the original question.

Comment: @scottishwildcat - Yes, this is true, but the question asks for a word to describe such people, not a word that always means such a person.